# Mathematic letter puzzle

Tags: mathematics, cipher

What word does this string result into?

The ; sign marks separation between letters.

**i-a;2b+a;2f;2f;e+e+e;**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> hello

Reasoning:

> Using the usual alphabet-to-numbers conversion (a=1, b=2, and so on).

Comment: How to you found ll and o?(I found just h and e.)

Comment: @Ronronner 2f=2*f=2*6=12=l, and e+e+e=5+5+5=15=o

Comment: @Ronronner f=6 , 2f=12 so 12th letter is L

Comment: Ok, I understood!

Answer (score 2):

> I get HELLO
>  convert character to number with a starting as 1 and increment by 1
>  i - a gets you h  19[i]-1[a] = 18[h]
>  2b + a gets you 2(2[b]) + 1[a] = 5[e]
>  2f gets you 2(6[f]) = 12[l]
>  e + e + e gets you 5[e] + 5[e] + 5[e] = 15[o]